# Safari bug with transition and translateY: "jumping" element

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-transitions

I'm moving an element with translateY. Everything works fine under Chrome, Firefox, IE, old Edge *except* Safari (12.1.2 & 13.1.2) and [GNOME Web](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Web) (WebKit).

Under Safari the element "jumps". Here a small example (also available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tkrotoff/pen/OJLwQXx?editors=1100)):

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;

  transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
.child.move {
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  padding: 0; /* If 10px: no bug */
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" onclick="this.classList.toggle('move')">Click me</div>
</div>
```

I could not find answers on the [WebKit bug tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=transition%20translateY).

Do you know some workarounds?

Other Stack Overflow related issues:

- [css transform + width + left + top transition jump on safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56500594)
- [Transition both transform and size in Safari (9.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39399431)
- [Animating margins and padding with CSS Transition causes jumpy animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28203411)

Comment: Maybe use some other property like top / bottom for transition and moving the target element as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/29330961/4997994.

Comment: 4 years later and the issue is still present with Safari 17.3

Answer (score 6):

You can add: `transition-delay: 1ms;` which would force the padding property before the `transform` transition.

https://codepen.io/konstantin/pen/qBWJjjq

Comment: That works great with `transition: transform ...` but not with `transition: all ...` :-/

Comment: This is a great solution. Had the same issue with the logo animation here http://budapesturbanwalks.com (when viewport was below 991px and landscape and scroll position was not on top of the site). This solved it! It uses `transition: all`, but it works like charm.